# Mapping to varchar and nvarchar in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, varchar, nvarchar

If there are 2 columns in database, eg.

```
code varchar(3)
name nvarchar(50)
```

How to tell hibernate to pass varchar for searching by code?

In the hibernate mappings string is mapped to nvarchar and it produces queries like:

```
Select code, name From table where code=N'AAA'  (instead of code='AAA')
```

This is very bad as it causes index scan instead of index seek operation (scanning all index nodes instead of directly going to requested one)

As code is used in millions of rows as well as in several indexes and foreign keys, changing it from varchar to nvarchar will cause performance degradation (more IO operations as nvarchar uses twice more space than varchar).

Is there any way to tell hibernate to do mapping according to database type, not to Java type?

Thanks

Comment: Ask this question on http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers

Comment: you want to hiberntae make your field in database  by nvarchar type? or something else?

Comment: I want hibernate to pass varchar parameter to varchar type and nvarchar parameter to nvarchar type. 
eg. Insert Into table(varcharCol, nvarcharCol) Values ('aaa', N'aaa')

Comment: @Niikola, did you solve the problem? i have the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<type-mapping>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="string" />
 </type-mapping>
```

Add the above code in the hibernate reveng file.

Answer (score 9):

Probably you already solved this, but I had a similar problem.

I'm using jTDS JDBC driver and I solved the index scan problem by adding:

```
;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;prepareSQL=0
```

to the end of the jTDS connection string.

Probably it would not had solved your problem because by doing this, jTDS will only use VARCHAR (no NVARCHAR anymore).

Also, I had to disable the prepared SQL, because Hibernate is using 'like' instead of '=' when generating the queries and by using 'like' combined with a variable (SELECT ... WHERE column LIKE @var) causes an index scan (MSSQL 2000).

Comment: ;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false solved this problem for us. We did not need to add ;prepareSQL=0 since that was working correct for us. 

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about NHibernate rather than Hibernate because the latter does not use nvarchar in its default SqlServer dialect.

The way to solve your problem is to specify column type as "AnsiString" in your mapping:

```
<property name="Code" type="AnsiString"/>
```

Take a look at [this post](http://community.devpinoy.org/blogs/joeycalisay/archive/2007/05/11/nhibernate-unicodes-and-index.aspx) for more details.

Comment: We are using Hibernate and it is sending them as nvarchar (and it's causing the biggest performance hit on our SQL box because of the index scan)

Comment: Ran into the same problem... could not find much info so wrote it up here  http://toddstechnonsense.blogspot.com/2010/11/nhibernate-performance-ansi-string-vs.html

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate.properties set the property hibernate.connection.defaultNChar=false.

You can either hide your tables behind views or use nstring type. This type is available in hibernate-core 4.x. In hibernate-core 3.6.10.Final you will need to define the custom type nstring - see the comment in the url:
[Getting Hibernate and SQL Server to play nice with VARCHAR and NVARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237280/getting-hibernate-and-sql-server-to-play-nice-with-varchar-and-nvarchar/21427835#21427835).