# Specifying type of String while setting parameter value in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I wonder if it's possible to control the type of string (unicode or ANSI) while setting parameter value in the queries generated by Hibernate.
The problem is that the most of the tables in my application have varchar/char columns , and these columns are often appear in various filters.  However, all queries generated by Hibernate set parameter type to `nvarchar/nchar` making all indexes built on varchar columns pretty much unusable (index scan or full table scan instead of index seek/lookups ) .

As a workaround I set `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` ODBC connection parameter to false which solved performance issues , but I hope it should be the way to specify which string parameter has to be Unicode, and which  is just simple ANSI string.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory answer to this issue?

Comment: @daiscog : nope, I ended up with `sendStringParametersAsUnicode`

Answer (score 1):

I wont change any Issue in Hibernate or somewhere else because this is not the Point doing this in the current layer. It Is A configuration Issue so when you have to Configure the Connection Parameter (URL) you could have Adoptable Configuration where you do not need any Converions etc. so you can only switch the URL

e.g:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\MYSERVER;DatabaseName=MyDB;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
```

if you switch your DB to server MySQL or any other SQL Server so just change the Configuration not the Hibernate. I don't think that this would be the right place..

Hope that helps..

i found this List Helpfull :

```
Vendor              Parameter
-----------------------------------------
JSQLConnect         asciiStringParameters
JTDS                sendStringParametersAsUnicode
DataDirectConnect   sendStringParametersAsUnicode
Microsoft JDBC      sendStringParametersAsUnicode
```

http://emransharif.blogspot.de/2011/07/performance-issues-with-jdbc-drivers.html

cheers :)

Comment: This is what I'm doing now. What I don't like about this approach is that I can't then set nvarchar value properly...   In some cases I want `varchar` columns, in others - `nvarhar`. I'm certain column type should be decided based on domain requirements, not because of ORM preferences ....

Comment: have you seen this one here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237280/getting-hibernate-and-sql-server-to-play-nice-with-varchar-and-nvarchar

Comment: Yeah, I saw it ; it seems like another hack which requires adding user defined type to mimic functionality of `PreparedStatement.setString/setNString` .