# Why is this hql so much faster than using criteria?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2000

I'm using nhibernate as ORM. And one of my selections is incredible slow. The thing is, that it takes a long time to generate the sql. I'm sure it's not the sql query itself that's slow, because I timed the query itself with sql profiler. And it showed that there is a ~15 sec gap between starting to execute the nhibernate code, and the query being actually sent to the db. The generated SQL query itself is as fast as I'd expect it to be.

The selection code (in a repository) is as follows

```
public IEnumerable<Document> GetAllDocumentsReadyForDeletion()
{
    return from doc in _session.Query<Document>()
           where doc.StorageType == 'D'
           select doc;
}
```

I also tried:

```
return _session.CreateCriteria<Document>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("StorageType", 'D'))
        .List<Document>();
```

wich is the equivalent (right?). However, they both perform about the same (slow, like 15 secs to generate the sql query)

This however, performs as fast as I want it to be, and I have no clue why:

```
return _session.CreateQuery(
        "from Document doc where doc.StorageType = 'D'")
        .List<Document>();
```

I really want to use the linq to nhibernate version. Any idea why the code performs differently? (If you need more details, just ask!)

**Edit1**

Oh man, did I make a stupid mistake or what.. I mistakenly read the wrong column in the sql profiler.. The ehm, actual execution time for the first two are ~18 seconds, the 3rd is ~0 secs. I'm trying to find the differences in sql atm...

**Edit2**

This is actually becoming a whole different question. The resulting queries are almost exactly the same, except for that the first two are wrapped inside a "exec sp_executesql"

Now I've traced this a bit with query analyser, and the slow query has one step:

```
clustered index scan.
```

The fast query has two steps:

```
Index seek
Bookmark lookup
```

Any experiences with something like this?

Comment: "it takes a long time to generate the sql" -> you can't see that with the SQL profiler...

Comment: @Mauricio I meant I printed a message just before executing the code examples, and that at the same time I was monitoring the sql server with SQL profiler. This way I could see it took a long time from the beginning of executing the statement, to the sql query being sent to the sql server. I clarified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They actually generate different sql. One of wich uses the index, and one of wich doesn't. That's why. Why one of those uses the index and the other doesn't is content for a next question.

**(Simplified) Generated SQL**

Fast version:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM documents WHERE StorageType = 'D'
```

Slow version (both linq and criteria)(typing from memory atm, will check later):

```
sp_execsql N'SELECT Id, Name FROM documents WHERE StorageType = @p0', N'@p0 nchar(1)', N'D'
```

note that 'StorageType' is of type varchar(1). [This](http://toddstechnonsense.blogspot.com/2010/11/nhibernate-performance-ansi-string-vs.html) blog post explains why this is slow

> The problem here is that @p0 is passed as NCHAR(1) (aka a Unicode char) which does not match the index of the column with is non-Unicode.  This cases the index scan.

Apparently, an index scan takes about 17 secs on this table.

Comment: And I actually solved it using type="AnsiChar" (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306774/mapping-to-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-hibernate)

Comment: +1 Interesting, never thought that could cause such a delay! Could you post the different generated SQL queries?

Comment: Presumably just doing `SELECT Id, Name FROM documents WHERE StorageType = N'D'` would be slow too? I've encountered this issue quite a few times in the Java world... it gets rewritten to `WHERE cast(storagetype as nchar) = N'D'` or thereabouts, which is no longer a simple equality check of storagetype, therefore no index.

Comment: @araqnid Hah, you're actually right. But this get's me thinking again. Does this mean that I found a bug in nhibernate? Since it actually should generate with `N'D'` from the hql?

Comment: @Mr Happy: well, the `N'D'` format is a SQL Server-specific thing (at least, not a generic SQL thing) so it would be a bit painful to have the dialect cause that to happen. If you used a parameterised query, it (effectively) would, though.

Answer (score 0):

They are different paths in NHibernate to get the same data. They construct the queries using different code. There are discussions about the problem with NHibernate's linq provider. I ended up writing my own LINQ provider to give me LINQ into NHibernate that just creates the string in the second example then uses that to get the data.

Comment: But the Criteria method takes almost as long as the LINQ version. I thought the criteria api was rather mature; I must be doing something wrong xD

Comment: @Mr. Happy I didnt notice that was the NHibernate Criteria not the Method version of LINQ.

Comment: "I ended up writing my own LINQ provider" -> why not contribute to fix the NH LINQ provider instead? It seems you're pretty knowledgeable about this!