# Hibernate Converting 'NVARCHAR' to 'Serializable' on creating pojo classes from Sql Server tables

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, serialization

I am creating POJO classes and mapping files from Sql Server table by using Hibernate 4.3. But It is creating all 'nvarchar' fields to 'Serializable'. I want them to be 'String' type.

In my reveng.xml file I mentioned -

```
<type-mapping>
    <sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="string" />
    <sql-type jdbc-type="VARCHAR" hibernate-type="string" />
</type-mapping>
```

but no help.

My Reverse Engineering file is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate     Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-reverse-engineering>  
<schema-selection match-catalog="Copy_Up-Tourism" match-schema="dbo"/>
 <type-mapping>
    <sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="string" />
    <sql-type jdbc-type="VARCHAR" hibernate-type="string" />
</type-mapping>
<table-filter match-name="Contents"/>
 <table-filter match-name="CategoryDatas"/>
<table-filter match-name="TileExperience"/>
<table-filter match-name="PushTypes"/>
<table-filter match-name="DestinationDatas"/>
<table-filter match-name="PlaceDatas"/>
<table-filter match-name="EventDatas"/>
<table-filter match-name="YoutubeVideoTag"/>
<table-filter match-name="PushManagers"/>
<table-filter match-name="Activities"/>
<table-filter match-name="Languages"/>
<table-filter match-name="Categories"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

I tried many solutions in SO like [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072231/how-to-change-serializable-to-string-when-use-hibernate) but no help. Please help

Comment: Try to add also VARCHAR

Comment: Yes I did. but No help. Please see my update

Comment: did you manually create this file, or it was there before?

Comment: I created it by using Hibernate reverse engineering wizard in Netbeans. Then updated file manually to include Type-Mapping.

Comment: ok  try: java.lang.String instead of string, and clean/rebuild project, maven-> update

Answer (score 4):

Please do the following:

Change this:

```
<sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="string" />
```

To this:

```
<sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="java.lang.String" />
```

Add in your ***jdbc.properties*** file:

For *`oracle`*:

```
hibernatetool.metadatadialect=org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.OracleMetaDataDialect
```

For others:

`H2MetaDataDialect` *dialect for work around tweaks in the H2 database*

`JDBCMetaDataDialect`  *dialect that uses standard JDBC for reading metadata*

`MySQLMetaDataDialect`  *dialect that uses mysql for reading metadata*

Then as usual perform:

1. maven -> update
2. clean/rebuild project

Comment: I changed "string" to "java.lang.String"  in above code, rebuild the project and recreated POJO classes but still same issue.

Comment: did you add the change in jdbc.properties file?

Answer (score 0):

**My reveng file is like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <type-mapping>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="string" />
    </type-mapping>
    <table-filter match-name="TempTable"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

**POJO created**

```
public class TempTable  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int tempId;
     private String data;

    public TempTable() {
    }


    public TempTable(int tempId) {
        this.tempId = tempId;
    }
    public TempTable(String data) {
       this.data = data;
    }

    public int getTempId() {
        return this.tempId;
    }

    public void setTempId(int tempId) {
        this.tempId = tempId;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Conclusion just add

```
 <type-mapping>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="string" />
 </type-mapping>
```

to reveng file :)